# Json to XML with attributes rather than elements

Tags: python, json, xml, parsing, xmltodict

I need to parse an Json like:

```
{
"operacion": "ingresarOrdenBilateral",
"agente" : "0062",
"comitente" : 7211,
"fechaOrigen" : "2021-09-23T16:51:27.873-03:00",
"tipo" : "V",
"instrumento" : "GD30",
"tipoVenc" : "24",
"precio" : "100000000",
"cantidad" : "1",
"idOrigen" : 10699570
"ejecucion" : "SINCRONICA"
}
```

To this XML:

```
<ingresarOrdenBilateral 
agente="150" idOrigen="10039" fechaOrigen="2018-08-16T11:28:08.495-03:00" tipo="V" 
instrumento="AA17" tipoVenc="24" cantidad="1000000" precio="1625" formaOp="C" 
ejecucion="SINCRONICA"/>
```

I have tried the library xmltodict and dicttoxml but I can't manage to get XML using attributes rather than elements. Also I think that the XML format is not standard.

Thanks!

Comment: Show your code, and explain what you mean by *"I think that the XML format is not standard"*.

Comment: I've edited the question to what I think is the real problem -- using attributes vs elements; the fact that the element is then self-closing is an irrelevance

Comment: Please share the current effort (code) you have.

Comment: @Methizul, where this data stored? Do you read it from file? Or you retrieve it from some server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it can be done in one line using built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = {
    "operacion": "ingresarOrdenBilateral",
    "agente": "0062",
    "comitente": 7211,
    "fechaOrigen": "2021-09-23T16:51:27.873-03:00",
    "tipo": "V",
    "instrumento": "GD30",
    "tipoVenc": "24",
    "precio": "100000000",
    "cantidad": "1",
    "idOrigen": 10699570,
    "ejecucion": "SINCRONICA"
}
ET.dump(ET.Element(data.pop("operacion"), {k: str(v) for k, v in data.items()}))
```

Output:

```
<ingresarOrdenBilateral agente="0062" comitente="7211" fechaOrigen="2021-09-23T16:51:27.873-03:00" tipo="V" instrumento="GD30" tipoVenc="24" precio="100000000" cantidad="1" idOrigen="10699570" ejecucion="SINCRONICA" />
```

---

**Upd.** Assuming you're loading this JSON data either from file or server it's possible to pass [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) to `parse_int` argument of [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)/[`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)/[`requests.Response.json()`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json). It will force `int` fields to be parsed as `str`, so we can omit dict comprehension I've used in code above:

```py
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

str_data = '''{
    "operacion": "ingresarOrdenBilateral",
    "agente": "0062",
    "comitente": 7211,
    "fechaOrigen": "2021-09-23T16:51:27.873-03:00",
    "tipo": "V",
    "instrumento": "GD30",
    "tipoVenc": "24",
    "precio": "100000000",
    "cantidad": "1",
    "idOrigen": 10699570,
    "ejecucion": "SINCRONICA"
}'''
data = json.loads(str_data, parse_int=str)
ET.dump(ET.Element(data.pop("operacion"), data))
```

There're also `parse_float` and `parse_constant` which you can use in same way *(if needed, ofc)*.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using attributes rather than child elements is completely standard for this kind of structure. It's perhaps a little less common than using child elements, but it's not really unusual and it's certainly not non-standard.

Secondly, standard off-the-shelf converters between JSON and XML never give you enough control to produce exactly the target structure that you want. If you want a particular XML format, then you have to be prepared to do a transformation on the result, which is usually very easy to achieve with XSLT.

If you use XSLT 3.0 then you can do the JSON-to-XML conversion and the subsequent transformation within a single stylesheet; but otherwise, using your favourite library converter followed by an XSLT (1.0+) conversion is straightforward enough. You'll find plenty of examples of stylesheets that convert XML elements to attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is that simple the code below is able to do the job

```
data = {
"operacion": "ingresarOrdenBilateral",
"agente" : "0062",
"comitente" : 7211,
"fechaOrigen" : "2021-09-23T16:51:27.873-03:00",
"tipo" : "V",
"instrumento" : "GD30",
"tipoVenc" : "24",
"precio" : "100000000",
"cantidad" : "1",
"idOrigen" : 10699570,
"ejecucion" : "SINCRONICA"
}

xml = '<root>' + ' '.join(f'"{k}"="{v}"' for k,v in data.items()) + '</root>'
print(xml)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>"operacion"="ingresarOrdenBilateral" "agente"="0062" "comitente"="7211" "fechaOrigen"="2021-09-23T16:51:27.873-03:00" "tipo"="V" "instrumento"="GD30" "tipoVenc"="24" "precio"="100000000" "cantidad"="1" "idOrigen"="10699570" "ejecucion"="SINCRONICA"</root>
```

Comment: Your code won't produce output you attached. Your code won't produce output attached to question. Your code won't produce valid XML at all.